# When creating a custom Jekyll tag, what is the `tokens` arg used for?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

The Jekyll docs say we can [create a custom tag](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#tags):

```
module Jekyll
  class TestTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
      @tokens = tokens
    end
    def render(context)
      "text: #{@text} tokens: #{@tokens}"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('test', Jekyll::TestTag)
```

It seems like `initialize` is a built-in function, although the docs don't explicitly say that.

When I include this tag in a page:

```
{% test hallo world %}
```

I get:

```
text: hallo world tokens: {:locale=>#<Liquid::I18n:0x007fd62dbd5e38 
@path=”/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/locales/en.yml”>,
:line_numbers=>true}
```

Where are these tokens coming from? What do they do? Can I set tokens myself?

Comment: Just for reference, `initialize` is a reserved word in ruby to instantiate a new object.  In most languages it's called a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Where are these tokens coming from?

You are using the `super` keyword, that means it calls the `initialize` method of its parent class, in this case [Liquid::Tag](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/liquid/Liquid/Tag), it is the **constructor** of the class and creates a new instance of `Tag`.

## What do they do?

The `tokens` [argument](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers#arguments-and-initialization):

> is a hash that stores Liquid options. By default it
>   has two keys: :locale and :line_numbers, the first is a Liquid::I18n
>   object, and the second, a boolean parameter that determines if error
>   messages should display the line number the error occurred. This
>   argument is used mostly to display localized error messages on Liquid
>   built-in Tags and Filters.

Answer (score 1):

when defining a method using the `super` [keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/#M000034) tells the parser to look for a method of the same name along the lookup path.

[Liquid::Tag](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/liquid/Liquid/Tag#initialize-instance_method) has an initialize method, and that is where those tokens are most likely coming from.